# Secure keys in Java file like API keys, etc from hackers

Tags: java, android

I am building an Android app and I am worried about app security of API and other keys. So I need a method to secure them from hackers!

I have already tried to store these keys on Firebase but it is not a perfect method as it uses a lot of data on Firebase and took time to receive.

Comment: try using certificate verification and/or JNI

Comment: @TheBadak Neither of those is secure.  JNI is just making them reverse engineer trivial C code instead, you may actually be making it easier.  A certificate isn't securing it, they can just take your cert and use that.  The only secure thing is not to have it in the client at all.

Comment: https://medium.com/@sagarsuri56/secure-your-api-keys-locally-like-a-champ-985bb8bbed18

Comment: @A.easazadeh: re your edit, please do not add code formatting to non-code items. It does not make them more readable, unfortunately.

Comment: it would be helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A safe option would be saving the KEY API values inside the `local.properties` file.

Inside your `app/build.gradle` file add the reference to the API KEY:

```
android {
     ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "myAPI_KEY", "\"API_KEY_VALUE\"" 
        ...
    }
     ...

}
```

Inside the `local.properties` file add the entry that defines the value of the API KEY:

```
API_KEY_VALUE="AIzaSy..............."
```

then, build your project and you can get the value of the API KEY from the `BuildConfig` class, example:

```
 String myApiKey = BuildConfig.myAPI_KEY;
```

Comment: While Decompiling the .apk file by the hacker, they will easily get the Build.grdle and then They can misuse my API.

Comment: @MegamindCore no, the API KEY value is stored into local.properties file.

Comment: Yes, you are right as it is not inside built. Gradle

Comment: The code was just an example, Are you using SafetyNet?

Comment: sorry, For my silly mistake I thought that it would work like firebase retrieve data.